# How can I change the variable name?

Tags: lua

Code:

```
for k,v in pairs(self.Data) do
 print(k, v)
 exports.mongodb:updateOne({ collection="users", query = { _id = self.Data._id }, update = { ["$set"] = { k = v } } })
end
```

So I try to update the database but it only updates `k`, it doesn't update the rest from the table.

Comment: You probably mean `[k] = v`?